# Dustjs if condition for json

Tags: node.js, dust.js, kraken.js

How can i put proper condition check based on json data

I'm sending  json object from node layer to dust template, based on object value i want to hide/show data. Nodejs frameworke used is `krajenjs 0.7.5`

```
1.{ access : {  home : false} }

2.{ access : {  home : false} }
```

Worked fine for `2`

```
{@if cond="{access.home}"}
<div>Home</div>
{/if}
```

How to make it work for  `1` using `if condition` notation

or

like below which does not work 
[[--------Update----------]] This works fine

```
{?access.home}
<div>Home</div>
{/access.home}


{^access.home}
<div>Home</div>
{/access.home}
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more descriptive about what output you are hoping for. Using your data, I am getting the expected output for both `?` and `^`. Also, I would avoid using the `@if` helper. It has been deprecated due to security concerns.

Comment: im using `dustjs-linkedin - 2.0.3` and  `dustjs-helpers - 1.1.2 ` and `?` and `^` is throwing error.
which version are you using?

Comment: #1 and #2 look like the same JSON. Are they supposed to be?

Comment: It worked fine, i was doing in wrong way.
I used `@if cond` inside `?`and '^' and showed error. I changed everything to `?` and `^` and it worked fine.

Comment: Could you please post the answer so that this question is resolved...

Comment: Instead of two separate checks `{?access.home}` and `{^access.home}` you can merge them into one check using `{?access.home}condition true{:else}condition false{/access.home}`